Visual Studio 2022 : ASP.NET Core & React template not working
While trying to follow this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react?view=vs-2022) when I try to launch the project I get these errors in the command prompt

reactapp1.client@0.0.0 dev


vite

Error when starting dev server:

ReferenceError: structuredClone is not defined
at deepClone (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:10245:5)
at file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:10232:29
at Array.map ()
at deepClone (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:10232:18)
at deepClone (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:10237:21)
at deepClone (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:10237:21)
at mergeWithDefaults (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:10271:26)
at resolveBuildEnvironmentOptions (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:50302:18)
at resolveEnvironmentOptions (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:52831:12)
at resolveConfig (file:///C:/Container/Reactapptest/ReactApp1/reactapp1.client/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-yUJfKD1i.js:53080:45)
Press any key to continue . . .

It seems I've hit a environmental stumbling block. I'm using windows server 2019. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
Pieterjan's solution got me past the structured clone errors when I update to the latest version of node but now I'm getting deployment errors regarding this port.
Deployment of project 'C:\Container\Reactapptest\ReactApp1\reactapp1.client\reactapp1.client.esproj' failed. Port unavailable: 7009
2>An exception happened at deploy, the port 7009 configured on launch.json is unavailable.

Could you kindly check the node version in your windows server 2019 ? structuredClone was added in Node 17.

What Node version are you using? Also, in case you'd find the answer, feel free to open a pull-request on this repository if the template needs to be changed

Thanks! v16.17.0

Don't know for sure, but you could try setting "engines:node": "^16.17.0" like this. Or install node 18 or 20

Thanks, that got rid of that error updating the node, but now I'm having issues with this port- 7009.

Hi IjonTichy， from your error message, you are using vscode, so please share more details about how you create the spa template and deployment steps. And the vscode version and .net version are also important. We have to reproduce the issue in our side, then we can help you.
